# C# Property Access vs Interface Implementation

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I'm writing a class to represent a [Pivot](http://www.getpivot.com) Collection, the root object recognized by Pivot. A Collection has several attributes, a list of facet categories (each represented by a `FacetCategory` object) and a list of items (each represented by a `PivotItem` object). Therefore, an extremely simplified Collection reads:

```
public class PivotCollection
{
    private List<FacetCategory> categories;
    private List<PivotItem> items;
    // other attributes
}
```

What I'm unsure of is how to properly grant access to those two lists. Because declaration order of both facet categories and items is visible to the user, I can't use sets, but the class also shouldn't allow duplicate categories or items. Furthermore, I'd like to make the Collection object as easy to use as possible. So my choices are:

1. Have `PivotCollection` implement `IList<PivotItem>` and have accessor methods for `FacetCategory`: In this case, one would add an item to Collection `foo` by writing `foo.Add(bar)`. This works, but since a Collection is equally both kinds of list making it only pass as a list for one type (category or item) seems like a subpar solution.
2. Create nested wrapper classes for `List` (`CategoryList` and `ItemList`). This has the advantage of making a consistent interface but the downside is that these properties would no longer be able to serve as lists (because I need to override the non-virtual `Add` method I have to implement `IList` rather than subclass `List`. Implicit casting wouldn't work because that would return the `Add` method to its normal behavior.

Also, for reasons I can't figure out, `IList` is missing an `AddRange` method...

```
public class PivotCollection
{
    private class CategoryList: IList<FacetCategory>
    {
        // ...
    }

    private readonly CategoryList categories = new CategoryList();
    private readonly ItemList items = new ItemList();

    public CategoryList FacetCategories
    {
        get { return categories; }
        set { categories.Clear(); categories.AddRange(value); }
    }

    public ItemList Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set { items.Clear(); items.AddRange(value); }
    }
}
```

Finally, the third option is to combine options one and two, so that `PivotCollection` implements `IList<PivotItem>` and has a property `FacetCategories`.

**Question:** Which of these three is most appropriate, and why?

Comment: You should not make a class called `Collection`.  Choose a more specific name.

Comment: Edited to be `PivotCollection` - would that be better?

Comment: Since it's not (directly) a collection of objects, it probably shouldn't end in `Collection`.

Comment: The name came from the [CXML spec](http://www.getpivot.com/developer-info/xml-schema.aspx): Each class maps to a corresponding XML entity - `PivotItem`, `FacetCategory`, `Facet`, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do here is to create your own collection class that inherits [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132397.aspx) and overrides `InsertItem`.